# How to get break time of the Employees using MySQL Query only

Tags: mysql

```
id      staff_ID        STAFFNAME             CARDTIME
39618   1203024        BARAYUGA M.     2014-02-03 08:44:02
39618   1203024        BARAYUGA M.     2014-02-03 12:20:02
39618   1203024        BARAYUGA M.     2014-02-03 12:50:49
39618   1203024        BARAYUGA M.     2014-02-03 17:33:44
39622   1203056        LEONES M.       2014-02-03 12:00:21
39622   1203056        LEONES M.       2014-02-03 12:23:19
39622   1203056        LEONES M.       2014-02-03 13:22:33
39622   1203056        LEONES M.       2014-02-03 15:30:11
```

Above is my table `tbl_staff` in my database, is there a way that I can get the total break hours of each employees? using Mysql query only.

Here is my sample query that I am using right now.

```
SELECT 
  DATE,
  STAFFNAME, 
  LOGIN, LOGOUT, 
  SUCCESSFUL, 
  TIME,
  NUMBEROFTIME, 
  FIND_IN_SET(LOGIN,TIME),
  FIND_IN_SET(LOGOUT,TIME)
FROM 
(
    SELECT   
      DATE( CARDTIME ) AS DATE, 
      STAFFNAME,  
      MIN( CARDTIME )  AS LOGIN,  
      MAX( cardtime ) AS LOGOUT, 
      CASE 
        WHEN COUNT( CARDTIME ) %2 =0 THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
      END AS  'SUCCESSFUL', 
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(CARDTIME) ORDER BY (CARDTIME) )  AS TIME,
      COUNT(CARDTIME) as NUMBEROFTIME
    FROM tbl_staff
    GROUP BY STAFFNAME, DATE( CARDTIME )
) AS x
```

I already research how to get the break time but the example data is different from mine where there is no `LOGIN` and `LOGOUT`.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL allows you to write a query like this:

```
SELECT
  id, staff_ID, STAFFNAME,
  timediff(t3,t2) AS Break
FROM (
  SELECT
    id, staff_ID, STAFFNAME,
    DATE(CARDTIME) as carddate,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        GROUP_CONCAT(CARDTIME order by CARDTIME),
        ',',
        3),
      ',',
      -1) t3,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(
      GROUP_CONCAT(CARDTIME order by CARDTIME),
      ',',
      2),
    ',',
    -1) t2
  FROM
    tablename
  GROUP BY
    id, staff_ID, STAFFNAME,
    DATE(CARDTIME)
  ) s
```

it's not too optimized and not SQL standard, and you should also be sure that there are four cardtimes every day. But it should return the result that you need.

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01675/1).

**Edit**

If employes can have less or more than 4 cardtime entries, you should consider using this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT
    id,
    staff_ID,
    STAFFNAME,
    DATE(CARDTIME) AS card_day,
    timediff(next_CARDTIME,CARDTIME) As t_diff,
    CASE WHEN
      CASE WHEN next_CARDTIME IS NULL THEN @n:=-1 ELSE @n:=@n+1 END MOD 2 = 0
      THEN 'Work' ELSE 'Break'
    END AS type
  FROM (
    SELECT
      t1.id,
      t1.staff_ID,
      t1.STAFFNAME,
      t1.CARDTIME,
      MIN(t2.CARDTIME) next_CARDTIME
    FROM
      tablename t1 LEFT JOIN tablename t2
      ON (t1.id, t1.staff_ID) = (t2.id, t2.staff_ID)
         AND DATE(t1.cardtime)=DATE(t2.cardtime)
         AND t1.cardtime<t2.cardtime
    GROUP BY
      t1.id, t1.staff_ID, t1.STAFFNAME, t1.CARDTIME
    ORDER BY
      t1.id, t1.staff_ID, t1.STAFFNAME, t1.CARDTIME
    ) s, (SELECT @n:=-1) r
  ) s
WHERE t_diff IS NOT NULL
```

of course if number of cardtime entries is odd, last entry of the day will be a break. Have a look at this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb9b345/1).

Comment: @kenjilaurel - Accept it if you found it helpful please, by checking the mark on the left of the answer, this how things work here. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi sir, your query is working, but how can make it more dynamic? because if the total entries is more than 4 times, the ouput of the query is invalid

Comment: @kenjilaurel if there are more than 4 entries, how do you want to calculate the break time?

Comment: in my database, the employees can have more than 4 cardtime entry, when I run you query sir, the output is not correct because it is only applicable for 4 cardtime per employees. Is there a way that the query is more dynamic? as long as the total count of card entries is even.

Comment: @kenjilaurel please see my edit! hope it is what you are looking for!

Comment: Hi Sir, your updated query is working great, last question sir, how can I add all the break time per employee? so I can get their total breaks per day. Thank you so much ! I appreciate your time in answering my question, you help a lot.

Comment: hi sir, please read my follow up comment , do you have idea how to acquire the output?

Comment: @kenjilaurel have a look at this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb9b345/26 the sum will be expressed in seconds

Comment: @fthiella  sir, is it possible to get the break time without using local variable @n?

Comment: can we produced same output by following this steps:
1.group_concat
2.find_in_set
3.using correlate + scalar subquery.